# can't read tag with TagLib

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

Downloaded taglib 1.9 from https://taglib.github.io/ and compiled with the instructions provided in the INSTALL file.

The code below crashes with error "The program has unexpectedly finished."

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include <taglib/mp4file.h> 
#include <taglib/mpegfile.h>
#include <taglib/fileref.h>
#include <taglib/taglib.h>
#include <taglib/tag.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TagLib::FileName fn(QString("C:/Users/Bill/Desktop/02 Am I Wrong.mp3").toStdString().c_str());
    TagLib::FileRef ref(fn);

    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(std::string(ref.tag()->artist().toCString()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

Running in debug mode show me null dereference fileref.cpp at

```
bool FileRef::isNull() const
{
  return !d->file || !d->file->isValid();
}
```

Running Windows 10 insider preview with static built Qt 5.0.2

I've toiled and toiled and found no helpful result.

Answer (score 1):

The Pointer returned by `QString.toStdString()..c_str()` is only valid while the QString object is still alive. In your case that's only on the line where you're creating it.
So either keep a reference to your QString or don't use QString at all.

```
TagLib::FileRef ref("C:/Users/Bill/Desktop/02 Am I Wrong.mp3");
qDebug() << ref.tag()->artist().toCString();
```

Furthermore you should add some error checks. Here's an example without using qt:

```
#include <taglib/fileref.h>
#include <taglib/taglib.h>
#include <taglib/tag.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TagLib::FileRef ref("./Falco Benz - Hat Tricks (Original Mix).mp3");
    if(!ref.isNull() && ref.tag() != NULL) {
        std::cout << ref.tag()->artist().toCString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If I omit the error checks, and the file does not exists, I get a segfault.

Comment: I extended the answer with some error checks, now it works.
Are you sure that the filepath is correct (and that it's correctly escaped, if necessary) ? Try the path `C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\02 Am I Wrong.mp3`

Comment: Does not solve the problem. `ref.isNull()` is implemented as `return !d->file || !d->file->isValid();`. The error is because `file` is `NULL`.

Comment: if file is `NULL` the function would directly return true because of `return !d->file`. Did you meant to say `d` is `NULL` ?

Comment: sorry, my bad. `d` is `NULL`. And i've tested with any file that does not exist and `TagLib` reports `Could not open file`. What is going on?

Comment: On windows, `QMultimedia` works but `Taglib` does not work. On Linux `Taglib` works just fine but `QMultimedia` would not work. I'm totally screwed.

Comment: I can not reproduce your bug (I don't have a linux installation here).

Comment: Ideally you would provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including your project file or makefile), which shows the problem and submit that to their [Bugtracker](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/issues)

Comment: What you're saying "d is null" is really odd and I can hardly believe it after looking at the implementation of `fileref.cpp`.

Comment: May be a snapshot would explain better. http://picpaste.com/pics/error-kCRehYaY.1437658765.PNG for debug and http://pastebin.com/Ngtzv8VY for the code

Comment: Your project file looks good to me. I suggest you submit this to their bugtracker and tell them which compiler/platform you use. Ideally you would remove the qt dependency, since it doesn't seem to be qt related at all.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think i'll port my program to C# and try `taglib` for .net if i'm not able to fix this.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Have you tried using another one?

Comment: I built my Qt with VC++ 11 (VS 2012), same version is compiled  `taglib`. comiling with VC++ 12 gives me `error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in main.obj` I'll get similar error if i try with VC++14

Comment: Then i have to rebuild Qt.. (oh no)

Comment: You don't have to build QT. It's prebuilt for mingw. Just use the official installer and select mingw. http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-windows-x86-online.exe

Comment: I know about that version.The thing is i wanted the static version. That's why i built from source. But i'll try the prebuilt mingw version now. I'll get back soon for results.